# Adding breaklines and formatting your xml content

Tags: xml, html

I want to bold and add breaks into my xml `<Content>` with html tags.
This is the method I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Response>

<Count>1</Count>


-<Result>


-<result>

<Title>Title Title</Title>

<Content><h1><b>Subheading</b></h1> <h3>Hello everyone</h3><br/> Date：23th November<br/> <br/></Content>

<Image/>

<CreatedAt>2015-12-14T06:42:55.267Z</CreatedAt>

<ModifiedAt>2015-12-14T07:17:19.577Z</ModifiedAt>

<CreatedBy>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</CreatedBy>

<ModifiedBy>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</ModifiedBy>

<Owner>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Owner>

<Link/>

<Group>TSTSCC</Group>

<Id>e7e87f30-a22d-11e5-8340-f3025c46ea4f</Id>

</result>

</Result>

</Response>
```

The result above showed every single tag I used like : `<b>Hi</b>`
 instead of **Hi**.

So how do I format my above xml content with html tags?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Also I have tried "\t" and "\n" as well which didn't work either.

Comment: I'm confused by your dash marks as in `-<Result>` and `-<result>`. Do they invalidate your XML? Aside from that, I'm certain you need XSLT to transform your XML into formatted output like HTML. Reference -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT

Comment: It depends on how you are rendering your XML.  I assume you want to export the contents of your Content element as HTML.  If you using XSL, use <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select='//Content'/>  This will ensure the HTML content stays where you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML does not have any default semantics, so there is no way for the browser to know that "h1" in this case is and HTML "h1". In fact, it very specifically is not an HTML "h1", but an "h1" in whatever language your XML file is in, which the browser knows nothing about.

To make your "h1" be an HTML "h1" you would need to cast it into the HTML namespace.

```
 <h1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Whether it would then be displayed as you want would then depend on whether the browser or editor you are using recognized and processed HTML in the context of 
an XML file. Most editors, I suspect, would still show you the text rather than
applying the formatting.

You don't actually say where you are displaying this file, but if it is in a browser, you can either transform the XML to HTML, or you can supply a CSS stylesheet to tell the browser how to display the text. But that will mean you also have to deal with how to make the rest of your XML appear as tagged text
rather than being formatted per the stylesheet.